# Accessing Jenkins Job attributes from another job

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins groovy template script that is looping through a list of auxiliary models called `services`. Each auxiliary model has a job called `reportableJob` as an attribute. These "reportable jobs" all have an attribute called `branch`. How can I access this attribute?

Here's my general thinking:

```
for (i=0; i< services.size(); i++) {
    def job = services[i].reportableJob
    def branch = job.branch
    echo "${branch}"
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: branch for class: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob
```

Comment: Are you using [tag:jenkins-pipeline] plugin or [tag:jenkins-job-dsl] plugin - or really both?

Comment: Just using the pipeline plugin.

Comment: I mean.. yes the [`WorkflowJob`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/blob/6e3d7f4c1bea84eadcf0e14d6b2044116da88a48/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.java) doesn't have such attribute. What about [`getSCMs()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/blob/6e3d7f4c1bea84eadcf0e14d6b2044116da88a48/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.java#L523)?

Comment: Right, a simple WorkflowJob doesn't have that attribute, but this job is an instance of a template which does have that attribute. Unfortunately some of the attributes I need are unrelated to SCM.

Comment: But it actually seems that it's _not_ an instance of a class that has such property. The error says `WorkflowJob`.

Comment: Hmm is there a way to cast it as the job type that has that attribute? I ask because I'm certain that this WorkflowJob is an instance of a template which has a "branch" attribute. (Thanks by the way for helping!)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's where my knowledge also ends. The [`Job`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Job.java) class that it extends also lacks any `branch` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out, good to know:

```
for (i=0; i< services.size(); i++) {
    def job = services[i].reportableJob
    def instance = com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.modeling.impl.entity.EntityInstance.from(job)
    echo "Branch: ${instance.getValue("branch")}"
}
```